# Delphi XE2 datasnap callback example

Tags: delphi, callback, delphi-xe2, datasnap

> I am trying to create a small example of how to exchange objects using calbacks, but I am experiencing some problems.
>
> 1. When server creates and broadcasts objects, some clients callback connections are closed randomly with time (sometimes after server has sent like 100.000 objects, sometimes after 100 even less).
> 2. When a client calls a server method to broadcasts an object, it happens offten that the client connection to the server is closed.
>      All this is stopping me from converting my current project to a real client server one.
>      Here is my source, including the executables for both server and client:
>      [DataSnapExample.rar](http://uploading.com/files/3f51dad2/DataSnapExample.rar/)

P.S. I have tried Mat DeLong's Monitoring demo, I've put a ttimer on server's main form, that calls the broadcast message menu event, and result was same - after sending messages for a while, some clients are disconnected. I'm afraid this happens because of a client-server bug in Delphi XE2 Datasnap. Here is the demo: [DataSnap XE2 - Unified Connection Monitoring Sample Component](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28625)

Can someone tell me if it is my fault or not?
Thanks...

Comment: +1 to offset drive-by downvote